# Replace a 3.7 V speaker battery with power supply

Tags: power-supply, lithium-ion

I have a JBL Charge 3 speaker with a dead Lithium Ion battery. The battery is a 3.7V 6000 mAh GSP1029102A like [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/3-7V-6000mAh-GSP1029102A-Battery-For-JBL-Charge-3-Bluetooth-Wireless-Audio/203172602955).

I want to be able to use the speaker without the battery - using only the power supply, to act like a soundbar with my computer. I intend to use it at about 20% of the volume.

I tried to turn it on without the battery, using only the charger but it only blinks a red LED and do not turns on.

My question is: Is it possible to build a power supply to connect as a "fake" battery or use the 5 V 2.5 A USB charger as a power input deactivating the "no battery" feature?

Comment: The original battery has 4 or 5 wires. your power supply has only 2 wires.

Comment: @Audioguru I know. I would like to know if there’s a way to make an adaptor to this connection

Comment: Obvious answer is 'Yes'. Since the manufacturer have it working with a battery, it can be done with a PSU as well.

Comment: Well....... Here's the block diagram. https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1844723/Jbl-Charge-3.html?page=23#manual As you can see, there's a boost converter powering the audio amp, supplying it with up to about 11 volts. 20 watts at 11v is a touch under 2amps. *Perhaps* you can trick the device and just feed it 5v (but I wouldn't hold my breath while I tried to work out how) Your best bet might simply to find an adjustable buck converter, which you set to 4.2v (LiPo cells are 4.2v when fully charged) and connect the output to the battery's input. Since the cells aren't n series, I'd be surprised

Comment: if you've actually got more than 2 wires from the battery. Sure, there's 5 physical wires, but I'd expect there just to be two different values - 0v and batteryVoltage. The extra 3 wires are quite likely just connected in parallel. You can buy a buck converter online for a few dollars.
I would consider simply replacing the battery pack with an 18650 cells.
I would also consider buying a well-rated, but cheaper replacement battery. The one you show is $35US and in the "You may also like" section at the bottom of the page, there's a battery which includes some simple tools  and costs $15.99 US

Comment: Dirt-cheap batteries are often (but not always) garbage, yet premium priced ones are sometimes only premium in price. I bought an RC helicopter batteries at the model-shop - It cost me $16. I found some online for $1.20 which worked better than the $16 one. That was over 10 years ago and these days many cheap cells are simply reclaimed from old goods and have a new heat-shrink wrapping applied!! I've even bought new goods with a 5,000 mAh rating, ret discovered 4,000 mAh cells inside - even the big-box stores get scammed!

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I just disassembled the USB cable, cut the five wires of the battery connector, and plugged the two power wires of the USB cable into both ends of the battery connector.

I know it's not the right approach, considering the voltage difference, but it's working fine.

Comment: I am glad to hear that it works fine when powered with 5V USB.